# How can I build a multicore program using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

we want to improve the code performance over a huge Pandas DataFrame using Multi-Core Parallel Programming. The kind of functions that we want to performance are of the following types: single entry (like the square function, logarithm, inverse, exponential) and binary entry (like the sum of two variables, multiplication of two variables, division of two variables). That set of functions will be applied over all the possible variable combinaions in the origial DataFrame. An example of the kind of functions that we want to performance in Multi-Core paradigm are:

```
  import pandas as pd

    data1 = pd.read_csv("data1_path.csv")
    data2 = pd.read_csv("data2_path.csv")

    def df_square(DF):
        aux_DF = pd.DataFrame()    
        for i in DF.keys():
            aux_DF[i + str(**2)] = DF[i]*DF[i]
        return aux_DF

    def df_sum(DF1, DF2):
        aux_DF = pd.Data_Frame()
        for i in DF1.keys()
            for j in DF2.keys():
                aux_DF[i + str(+) + j] = DF1[i] + DF2[j]
        return aux_DF

    square = df_square(data1)
    sum = df_sum(data1, data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for a [`dask`](https://dask.org/) which for the most part is a drop-in replacement for `pandas` but works in parallel. I suggest you give it a go.

If what you want to do is really perform some matrix operations then have a look at *[vectorized](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html)* operations provided in [`NumPy`](https://numpy.org/).